# jquery - return value using ajax result on success

Tags: jquery

I have a small problem with jQuery `$.ajax()` function.

I have a form  where every click on the radio button or selection from the dropdown menu creates a session variable with the selected value.

Now - I have one of the dropdown menus which have 4 options - the first one (with label None) has a `value=""` other have their ids.

What I want to happen is to None option (with blank value) to remove the session and other to create one, but only if session with this specific select name doesn't already exist - as all other options have the same amount assigned to it - it's just indicating which one was selected.

I'm not sure if that makes sense - but have a look at the code - perhaps this will make it clearer:

```
$("#add_ons select").change(function() {
        // get current price of the addons
        var order_price_addon = $(".order_price_addon").text();
        // get price of the clicked radio button from the rel attribute
        var add = $(this).children('option').attr('label');
        var name = $(this).attr('name');
        var val = $(this).val();
        
        
        if(val == "") {
            var price = parseInt(order_price_addon) - parseInt(add);
            removeSession(name);
        } else {
            if(isSession(name) == 0) {
                var price = parseInt(order_price_addon) + parseInt(add);
            }   
            setSession(name, val);              
        }
        
        $(".order_price_addon").html(price);    
        setSession('order_price_addon', price);         
        updateTotal();
});
```

so - first of all when the `#add_ons` select menu triggers "change" we get some values from a few elements for calculations.

we get the label attribute of the option from our select which stores the value to be added to the total, name of the select to create session with this name and value to later check which one was selected.

now - we check whether the `val == ""` (which would indicate that None option has been selected) and we deduct the amount from the total as well as remove the session with the select's name.

After this is where the problem starts - `else` statement.

Else - we want to check whether the `isSession()` function with the name of our selector returns 0 or 1 - if it returns 0  then we add to the total the value stored in the label attribute, but if it returns 1 - that would suggest that session already exists - then we only change the value of this session by recreating it - but the amount isn't added to it.

Now `isSession` function looks like this:

```
function isSession(selector) {
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: '/order.html',
        data: ({ issession : 1, selector: selector }),
        dataType: "html",
        success: function(data) {
            return data;
        },
        error: function() {
            alert('Error occured');
        }
    });
}
```

Now - the problem is - that I don't know whether using `return` will return the result from the function - as it doesn't seem to work - however, if I put the "data" in the success: section into the `alert()` - it does seem to return the right value.

Does anyone know how to return the value from the function and then compare it in the next statement?

---

Thanks guys - I've tried it in the following way:

```
function isSession(selector) {
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: '/order.html',
        data: ({ issession : 1, selector: selector }),
        dataType: "html",
        success: function(data) {
            updateResult(data);
        },
        error: function() {
            alert('Error occured');
        }
    });
}
```

then the `updateResult()` function:

```
function updateResult(data) {
    result = data;
}
```

`result` - is the global variable - which I'm then trying to read:

```
$("#add_ons select").change(function() {
        // get current price of the addons
        var order_price_addon = $(".order_price_addon").text();
        // get price of the clicked radio button from the rel attribute
        var add = $(this).children('option').attr('label');
        var name = $(this).attr('name');
        var val = $(this).val();
        
        
        if(val == "") {
            var price = parseInt(order_price_addon) - parseInt(add);
            removeSession(name);
        } else {
            isSession(name);
            if(result == 0) {
                var price = parseInt(order_price_addon) + parseInt(add);
            }   
            setSession(name, val);              
        }
        
        $(".order_price_addon").html(price);    
        setSession('order_price_addon', price);         
        updateTotal();
    });
```

but for some reason - it doesn't work - any idea?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to return the response from an AJAX call?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-to-return-the-response-from-an-ajax-call)

Comment: It may help solve this problem: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-do-i-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call/57968689#57968689

Answer (score 135, accepted):

The trouble is that you can not return a value from an asynchronous call, like an AJAX request, and expect it to work.

The reason is that the code waiting for the response has already executed by the time the response is received.

The solution to this problem is to run the necessary code *inside* the `success:` callback. That way it is accessing the `data` only when it is available.

```
function isSession(selector) {
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: '/order.html',
        data: ({ issession : 1, selector: selector }),
        dataType: "html",
        success: function(data) {
            // Run the code here that needs
            //    to access the data returned
            return data;
        },
        error: function() {
            alert('Error occured');
        }
    });
}
```

Another possibility (which is effectively the same thing) is to call a function inside your `success:` callback that passes the data when it is available.

```
function isSession(selector) {
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: '/order.html',
        data: ({ issession : 1, selector: selector }),
        dataType: "html",
        success: function(data) {
                // Call this function on success
            someFunction( data );
            return data;
        },
        error: function() {
            alert('Error occured');
        }
    });
}

function someFunction( data ) {
    // Do something with your data
}
```

Comment: You CAN return a value from an AJAX request, but that's only if you make it *non-asynchronous* (set the option `async: false`). In some cases, having an asynchronous call is not requirement. More on jquery.ajax() doc http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/ , not that `As of jQuery 1.8, the use of async: false with jqXHR ($.Deferred) is deprecated;`

Comment: "Non-asynchronous" can of course also be referred to as "synchronous" ;)

Comment: in both methods you suggested; ie. run the function withing success, then you have to write multiple ajax for different scenarios. this won't help in creating a global ajax wrapper , engine.

Comment: It seems, async: false is now deprecated and all of the processing needs to be done in the callback functions.

Answer (score 41):

There are many ways to get jQuery AJAX response. I am sharing with you two common approaches:

**First:**

> use **async=false** and within function return ajax-object and later get
>   response ajax-object.responseText

```
/**
 * jQuery ajax method with async = false, to return response
 * @param  {mix}  selector - your selector
 * @return {mix}           - your ajax response/error
 */
function isSession(selector) {
    return $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: '/order.html',
        data: {
            issession: 1,
            selector: selector
        },
        dataType: "html",
        async: !1,
        error: function() {
            alert("Error occured")
        }
    });
}
// global param
var selector = !0;
// get return ajax object
var ajaxObj = isSession(selector);
// store ajax response in var
var ajaxResponse = ajaxObj.responseText;
// check ajax response
console.log(ajaxResponse);
// your ajax callback function for success
ajaxObj.success(function(response) {
    alert(response);
});
```

**Second:**

> use **$.extend** 
>   method and make a new function like ajax

```
/**
 * xResponse function
 *
 * xResponse method is made to return jQuery ajax response
 * 
 * @param  {string} url   [your url or file]
 * @param  {object} your ajax param
 * @return {mix}       [ajax response]
 */
$.extend({
    xResponse: function(url, data) {
        // local var
        var theResponse = null;
        // jQuery ajax
        $.ajax({
            url: url,
            type: 'POST',
            data: data,
            dataType: "html",
            async: false,
            success: function(respText) {
                theResponse = respText;
            }
        });
        // Return the response text
        return theResponse;
    }
});

// set ajax response in var
var xData = $.xResponse('temp.html', {issession: 1,selector: true});

// see response in console
console.log(xData);
```

you can make it as large as you want...

Comment: Nice idea but `ajaxObj['responseText']` doesn't exist when you're defining `var ajaxResponse`

Comment: Perfect!! your first solution saved me

Comment: second method is 100% A OK! ;)

Comment: As of jQuery 1.8, the use of async: false is deprecated!

Answer (score 19):

Although all the approaches regarding the use of `async: false` are not good because of its deprecation and stuck the page untill the request comes back. Thus here are 2 ways to do it:

**1st: Return whole ajax response in a function and then make use of `done` function to capture the response when the request is completed.(RECOMMENDED, THE BEST WAY)**

```
function getAjax(url, data){
    return $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url : url,              
        data: data,
        dataType: 'JSON',
        //async: true,  //NOT NEEDED
        success: function(response) {
            //Data = response;
        }
    });
 }
```

**CALL THE ABOVE LIKE SO:**

```
getAjax(youUrl, yourData).done(function(response){
    console.log(response);
});
```

**FOR MULTIPLE AJAX CALLS MAKE USE OF `$.when` :**

```
$.when( getAjax(youUrl, yourData), getAjax2(yourUrl2, yourData2) ).done(function(response){
    console.log(response);
});
```

**2nd: Store the response in a cookie and then outside of the ajax call get that cookie value.(NOT RECOMMENDED)**

```
        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url : url,              
            data: data,
            //async: false,    // No need to use this
            success: function(response) {
                Cookies.set(name, response);
            }
        });

        // Outside of the ajax call
        var response = Cookies.get(name);
```

**NOTE:** In the exmple above `jquery cookies` library is used.It is quite lightweight and works as snappy. Here is the link https://github.com/js-cookie/js-cookie

Comment: The first method is outputting my whole PHP code instead of the echo output.

Comment: @AldrinSaurovSarker Make sure your datatype is correct and your server is accepting it.

Answer (score 16):

I saw the answers here and although helpful, they weren't exactly what I wanted since I had to alter a lot of my code.

What worked out for me, was doing something like this:

```
function isSession(selector) {
    //line added for the var that will have the result
    var result = false;
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: '/order.html',
        data: ({ issession : 1, selector: selector }),
        dataType: "html",
        //line added to get ajax response in sync
        async: false,
        success: function(data) {
            //line added to save ajax response in var result
            result = data;
        },
        error: function() {
            alert('Error occured');
        }
    });
    //line added to return ajax response
    return result;
}
```

Hope helps someone

anakin

Comment: You actually just turn off async

Comment: `async: false` is very helpful.

Answer (score 8):

**EDIT: This is quite old, and ugly, don't do this. You should use callbacks: https://stackoverflow.com/a/5316755/591257**

**EDIT 2:**
See the [fetch API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API)

Had same problem, solved it this way, using a global var. Not sure if it's the best but surely works. On error you get an empty string (myVar = ''), so you can handle that as needed.

```
var myVar = '';
function isSession(selector) {
  $.ajax({
    'type': 'POST',
    'url': '/order.html',
    'data': {
      'issession': 1,
      'selector': selector
    },
    'dataType': 'html',
    'success': function(data) {
      myVar = data;
    },
    'error': function() {
      alert('Error occured');
    }
  });
  return myVar;
}
```

Comment: you also need to add `async: false` here, because in asynchronous-mode it's not guaranteed that `data` is saved into `myVar` before `myVar` is returned.

Comment: @low_rents, thanks for this comment.  I had a problem returning a value from an ajax call and this was the first thread I found (after many) that mentioned ```async: false```.  Worked perfectly for me.

Comment: Absolutely @low_rents but please don't realy on this answer, things have moved a lot since.

Answer (score 8):

With Help from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30734372/access-javascript-variable-inside-ajax-success?answertab=votes#tab-top)

```
function get_result(some_value) {
   var ret_val = {};
   $.ajax({
       url: '/some/url/to/fetch/from',
       type: 'GET',
       data: {'some_key': some_value},
       async: false,
       dataType: 'json'
   }).done(function (response) {
       ret_val = response;
   }).fail(function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
           ret_val = null;
       });
   return ret_val;
}
```

Hope this helps someone somewhere a bit.

Comment: The use of `async: false,` is prehistoric and is deprecated since jQuery v1.8, It will probably help no one

Answer (score 3):

Add `async: false` to your attributes list. This forces the javascript thread to wait until the return value is retrieved before moving on. Obviously, you wouldn't want to do this in every circumstance, but if a value is needed before proceeding, this will do it.

Comment: You should never ever set `async: false`. This blocks everyhing on the page for the duration of the retrieval. You know what the A in AJAX stands for: Asynchronous. The proper answer would be that OP needs to use the `success()` callback properly.

Comment: I acknowledged the fact that everything has to wait. Under certain circumstances, the calling function may need a returned value, such as adding a new record and needing a record id returned. Once you know the rules, you know when they can be broken. Never say never. Here's someone else who concurs. (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3880361/returning-the-response-from-an-jquery-ajax-call)

Comment: Doing it wrong over there as well, the described problem could be solved easily in an asynchronous manner. You don't gain anything by doing synchronous calls, on the contrary.

Comment: @nietonfir Why does the option even exist then?

Comment: @CharlesWood Solely for those who can't grasp the async nature of ajax.

Comment: @nietonfir : if you should never ever use `async: false` why would have jQuery implemented this option? if i don't load big amounts of data to the page and just handle an user event, it's ok that it blocks everything else in the short amount of time for that particular user. nothing wrong and nothing bad about it. (if used correctly it won't block anything because in that particular time no other actions for that particular user will occur)

Comment: @northkildonan No, it's not okay. A sync AJAX request is bad. It blocks the complete javascript thread with something that you can't control. You don't have control over the amount of time it may take to process the request: the connection might be unreliable, the server might take longer than expected, etc. The *only reason* it is in jQuery is that you might need to save data on page unload (the only place it doesn't really matter if it takes longer, as the user already expressed his desire to leave the page). Just look at the jQuery unit tests…

Comment: @nietonfir : no, it's perfectly fine to use `async: false`. sometimes you just need synchronous execution and that's what it's made for.

Comment: @northkildonan I'm sorry to disappoint you, but it's not fine. ;-) There might be edge cases (as the unload example I've given, but that's really it imho), but most of the time people just don't understand how to use callbacks and/or javascript properly.

Comment: @nietonfir it is totally fine. you don't seem to understand where synchronous execution still is useful. only cause AJAX is primarily build for asynchronous use, it doesn't mean that it's wrong to use it synchronously in cases where you need it. seems like you haven't quite understood the difference betweeen synchronous and asynchronous. maybe google it.

Comment: @northkildonan Please. This is your third comment and you didn't come up with an example (because there are close to none). At least you seem to know the meaning of a in ajax. Google it yourself, e.g. in Gecko 30 [„synchronous requests on the main thread have been deprecated due to the negative effects to the user experience“](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest/Synchronous_and_Asynchronous_Requests#Synchronous_request). And they also stat that „[…] asynchronous requests should be preferred to synchronous requests for performance reasons.“ Go figure.

Comment: @nietonfir i wondered how long it will take till you come up with examples. now i know.

Comment: @northkildonan oO You must be a troll…

Comment: Some people are too tight narcissists for ever admitting to be wrong; and when they can't deny it anymore then they mirror your arguments and put it on you (I had a girlfriend like that ). They are so detrimental for tech world and for the time of people trying to help on SO... [however, in the end also *jQuery* deprecated the `async` param]

Answer (score 2):

```
// Common ajax caller
function AjaxCall(url,successfunction){
  var targetUrl=url;
  $.ajax({
    'url': targetUrl,
    'type': 'GET',
    'dataType': 'json',
    'success': successfunction,
    'error': function() {
      alert("error");
    }
  });
}

// Calling Ajax
$(document).ready(function() {
  AjaxCall("productData.txt",ajaxSuccessFunction);
});

// Function details of success function
function ajaxSuccessFunction(d){
  alert(d.Pioneer.Product[0].category);
}
```

it may help, create a common ajax call function and attach a function which invoke when success the ajax call, see the example

Answer (score -1):

Hi try **async:false** in your ajax call..

Answer (score -1):

```
function get_rows(param) {
   var rows = '';
   $.ajax({
       url: 'https://www.exmple.com/test.php',
       type: 'POST',
       data: {'key': value},
       async: false,
       dataType: 'html'
   }).done(function (data) {
       rows = data;
   }).fail(function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
       rows = '';
   });
   return rows;
}
```

I recommend use `async: false`. It is very very helpful.