# Returning the response from an Jquery AJAX call

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have written a function, which has to check whether a username has been taken or not. Now when I call the function from another function, and alert it's return value:

```
 alert(checkusernameavailable('justausername'));
```

it says 'undefined'. I've searched high and low, but can't find what I'm doing wrong. I guess it should just return the php-echo in check.php, but it doesn't. Here's the function I wrote:

```
var checkusernameavailable = function(value)  {
    $.ajax({
      url: "check.php",
      type: "POST",
      async: false,
      cache: false,
      data: "username=" + value + "",

      success: function(response) {
        alert(response);
        return response;        
      },
      error: function() {
        alert('ajax error');
      }
    });
  }
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

AJAX calls are async, which means they only return data after the operation has completed. I.e. the method `checkusernameavailable` never returns any information (unless you tell it to within that method itself). You need to do the following:

```
// Just fire and forget the method
checkusernameavailable("userName");

// Change the success function to do any display you require
success: function(response) {
    alert(response);
    $("#SomeDiv").html(response);     
  },
```

The method fires the AJAX async method that posts to check.php. When the response is received, you then handle that response in function associated with the success callback of `$.ajax`. You can specify a function directly to that success callback as well:

```
// Change success to point to a function name
success: foo

// Create a function to handle the response
function foo(response)
{
   // Do something with response
}
```

**EDIT:**

As per the OP's comment, you need to change your AJAX call to be synchronous, instead of asynchronous (I've never done a synchronous call like this myself, so this is untested):

```
var ajaxResponse;

$.ajax({
    async: false, 
    success : function (response)
              {
                  ajaxResponse = response;
              },
    // other properties
});

return ajaxResponse;
```

Full API listing [here](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/).

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I understand it. But it doesn's solve my problem. Let me explain what I want a little further. I am firing the function checkusernameavailable from within another function, which fires when my form is submit. So what I'm doing is:
if (!checkusernameavailable(username_box.val())) {
return false; // don't submit the form
// and make some boxes red, unhiding multilingual error messages (Which - btw - means I can't insert the response directly into my html...)
}

Comment: @user468893 - See my edit. You need to make your Async AJAX call synchronous.

Comment: It already was, but that was not the trick :) The return value did the magic. Thanks!