# Return WinJS.xhr request results

Tags: javascript, windows, winjs, microsoft-metro

I am playing around with the Windows 8 Metro SDK atm but ran in some trouble using WinJS.xhr.
If instead of returning the WinJS.xhr in the getData function i return some json object everything works fine, but i want to return an json object produced by a xhr request.

What is wrong in my attempt here? Thanks!! :)

```
(function () {
    "use strict";

function getData() {
    return WinJS.xhr({ url: "http://stackoverflow.com" }).done(
        function (request) {
            var results = [];
            var Item = {
                title: "title",
                text: "some text goes here"
            }
            results.push(Item);
            return results;
        },
        function (request) {
            var results = [];
            results.push({ title: "error", text: "error text" });
            return results;
        }
    );
}

var categoryList = new WinJS.Binding.List(getData());


var publicMembers = { itemList: categoryList };
WinJS.Namespace.define("Data", publicMembers);

})();
```

Comment: It doesn't make sense to return results from asynchronous handlers.

Comment: If I declare `var results=[]` before using WinJS and returning it afterwards it is not changed at all, so i tried the return thing..
Whats the right way to do it?

Comment: You have to make your API asynchronous. Let a function be passed to your function, and then call it from the "success" handler.

Comment: [Here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3302702/jquery-return-value-using-ajax-result-on-success) is one of hundreds of other similar StackOverflow questions on the topic.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You won't be able to get your `getData` function to return the data itself - this is the nature of asynchronous operations in Javascript and Metro.

The `WinJS.xhr` function returns a `WinJS.Promise` object, which represents an asynchronous operation. You should return this `Promise` to your caller, who can use the `then` or `done` methods to register callback functions that will be notified when the operation is complete (in the terminology of Promises, when the `Promise` is *fulfilled*).

So, your caller of the getData function would look something like this:

```
function myFunc() {
    getData().then(function(xhr) {
        // ...do something with the data when it arrives...
    }, function(err) {
        // ...do something with the error
    });
}
```

Notice that the callbacks are passed the XMLHttpRequest object.

And your getData method becomes something like this:

```
function getData() {
    return WinJS.xhr({ url: "http://stackoverflow.com" })
}
```