# Access javascript variable inside ajax success

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

```
var flag = false; //True if checkbox is checked
$.ajax({
    ... //type, url, beforeSend, I'm not able to access flag here
    success: function(){
        // I'm not able to access flag here
    }
});
```

Inside ajax, if I try to access `flag` it says it is not defined. How can I use it inside ajax function?

Any Idea?

Both flag and ajax is body of a function. Nothing else is present inside that function.

Comment: because, flag will be out of scope once the ajax call triggers the success call back.

Comment: just put the `var flag = false; ` inside the success function.

Comment: store it as global? window.flag = false;

Comment: i don't want to use gloabl. How will it become out of scope?

Comment: @GopsAB Because, ajax call will be executed asynchronously. If you still want to access that variable in success call back, then you have to make that call synchronous, by setting the `async` parameter `false`

Comment: `$.ajax(success: function() {}.bind(this));` Would probably work.

Comment: @RajaprabhuAravindasamy No, `success` doesn't magically remove variable from context. Here the `flag` variable is even not accessible from ajax option so OP is setting it outside of ajax method scope$

Comment: Where exactly are you defining flag?  I did a test and it worked fine.  Closures means that if `flag` and the `$.ajax` call are *at the same scope* then flag will be available (and it is).  There's some missing code in your question...

Comment: I get the feeling this isn't your actual code. This should work fine http://jsfiddle.net/djgdggay/

Comment: @freedomn-m flag and ajax is present inside a function. Nothing else is present inside that function

Comment: @GopsAB Are you sure you don't modify `flag` elsewhere?

Comment: `var flag = false; //True if checkbox is checked` sounds like you are setting it inside a change/click handler. Your question missing some context to make it understandable

Comment: @GopsAB You misunderstand me. I'm not saying this isn't *your own* code, I'm saying that the code you posted isn't representative of the problem you describe.

Comment: I also created a jsfiddle showing the code in the question working (with both true and false).  https://jsfiddle.net/L45oagrv/  Can you generate a jsfiddle with it *not* working?

Comment: I have voted to close this question, 2more people vote to close this. thanks

Answer (score 15):

You have access to the variable if you make it by reference. All objects in Javascript are referenced values, just the primitive values aren't (such as: int, string, bool, etc...)

So you can either declare your flag as an object:

```
var flag = {}; //use object to endure references.

$.ajax({
    ... //type, url, beforeSend, I'm not able to access flag here
    success: function(){
        console.log(flag) //you should have access
    }
});
```

Or force the success function to have the parameters you want:

```
var flag = true; //True if checkbox is checked

$.ajax({
    ... //type, url, beforeSend, I'm not able to access flag here
    success: function(flag){
        console.log(flag) //you should have access
    }.bind(this, flag) // Bind set first the function scope, and then the parameters. So success function will set to it's parameter array, `flag`
});
```

Comment: You don't need to set context of success callback here. OP commented `//type,url,beforeSend, I cannot able to access flag here` so this would be the same with `bind(this, flag)`

Comment: Can any of you guys help me out with this problem?    https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49122972/hide-jquery-elements-in-an-ajax-function

Answer (score 0):

Here is one way. The beforeSend callback option gives you access to both the jqXHR object and the ajax settings object.

You won't be able to use caturl in the append of error, as it will not be in synch with the request throwing error.

```
 $.ajax({
    /* url, data ...& other opts*/
    beforeSend:function( jqXHR, settings){
        /* add url property and get value from settings (or from caturl)*/
         jqXHR.url= settings.url;
   },
   /* error to be deprecated in jQuery 1.8 , superseded by "fail" */
   error: function(jqXHR, , textStatus, error){
       var url=jqXHR.url;
     /* replace caturl with url in your append */ 
     $('#showdata').prepend("ERROR : '" + error + "' trying to access: " + url + "</br>");
   }
```