# Loop of ajax calls inside an ajax Call variables are not updating

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I am trying to make some requests to an url and dependening on the length of the data that I get as a response to make a for loop length times, this is an example:

```
<script>

    var auxData;
    var message;
    $.ajax({
        url: "some url",
        type: "GET",
        dataType: "json",
        success: function (result) {
            auxData = eval(result["Some key"])
            for(var i = 0, l = (auxData.length-1); i < l; ++i)
            {
                console.log(i)
                $.ajax({
                    url: "another url",
                    type: "GET",
                    dataType: "json",
                    success: function (result) {  
                        message = eval(resul["Some key"])
                        console.log("Value of" + i) //ALWAYS PRINTS 8
                        message= message[i] //RETURNS ERROR
                    }.bind(this) 
                });

            }
        }
    });
</script>
```

I can't put all code here since its so long and confusing, but what happens is if the length of the variable `auxData` is 9, the line `console.log(i)` prints in console:

```
0
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
```

Then After all this was printed the line `console.log("Value of" + i)` prints this:

```
8
8
8
8
8
8
8
8
8
```

And finally if I try to access `i` like `message= message[i]` it doesn't work, It's like the calls inside the for loop are made separately. I have searched about what could be the problem but the only solutions were making the variable `i` global using callbacks but I don't know how to do it, also found this answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30734372/access-javascript-variable-inside-ajax-success) in stackoverflow about Accessing javascript variable inside ajax success but it didn't work for me, any solution would be really appreciated.

Comment: I saw this but it has nothing to do with jquery and ajax calls

Comment: @ProgrammerMan: No, but it *does* have to do with the problem you're facing.  *Your problem* has nothing to do with jQuery and AJAX calls.

Comment: @ProgrammerMan jQuery is a library over JS and ajax call is an async call. So yes, they are called separately. So the issue is with accessing variable `i` value inside a function call, which the dupe addresses.

Comment: just nest your AJAX calls within an IFE and you should be good to go.