# returning array from function and assigning it to variable

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

I am trying to return an object array from a function and assign it to a variable

```
function contactsbuilder(contacts){
    var contactsarray = [];
    parent.$(contacts).each(function(i,contact){
        contactsarray.push(somevalues);
        if(contacts.length == i+1){
            console.log("coming in here?");
            return contactsarray;
        }
    });
};
```

Now I tried to assign it like

```
var contactsarray =contactsbuilder(customdetails.contacts);
```

but `contactsarray` always stays undefined even after the console log is made.  I tried setTimeout but no luck

I tried a simpler one without foreach

```
function sample(){
var xx= ["ss","ssdfds"];
return xx;
}
var something = sample()
```

Now something gets array value, what is wrong in my case?

Comment: what should ` parent.$(contacts)` mean?

Comment: it is just an for each for an array of objects $(somearray).each

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to returning the array inside the `each()` callback which doesn't have any effect. And nothing is returning from the `contactsbuilder` function, so move the return statement outside.

```
function contactsbuilder(contacts){
    var contactsarray = [];
    parent.$(contacts).each(function(i,contact){
        contactsarray.push(somevalues);
        if(contacts.length == i+1){
            console.log("coming in here?");
        }
    });
    return contactsarray;// return the array
};
```

Comment: thanks, wont it return empty array if it has like 1000 values in it?  or when I want to make some ajax calls and return values?

Comment: @vignesh : I couldn't get you

Comment: for example, if I want to make some ajax call inside that $().each, wont it return the contactsarray before the ajax call returns some value?

Comment: @vignesh :  ajax is asynchronous  and it may complete any time .... the function will not wait for the ajax to execute

Comment: thanks ji, what should i do if i am going to use an ajax call inside that function and return value based on its result?

Comment: @vignesh : do whatever you want to do inside the success handler , call function inside from it.... ref : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3302702/jquery-return-value-using-ajax-result-on-success