# Get AJAX value and Store in a php variable

Tags: php, ajax

how do I get this ajax value #name and store it in a php variable? what i have done is put it in a HTML.

```
<p id="name"></p>


    setInterval(function(){

    $.ajax({
        url:"count.php", 
        type:"GET", 
        async:true, 
        cache:false, 
        success:function(count)
        {
            $("#name").html(count);

        }
    });

},1000);
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [jquery - return value using ajax result on success](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3302702/jquery-return-value-using-ajax-result-on-success)

Answer (score 0):

Use `data` to pass the variable to server. i.e. to count.php

```
 <p id="name"></p>
        setInterval(function(){
        var name=$("#name").val();
        $.ajax({
            url:"count.php",
            data:{name:name}, 
            type:"GET", 
            async:true, 
            cache:false, 
            success:function(count)
            {
               var res = $.parseJSON(count);
               var result= res.name;
               $("#name").html(result);
            }
        });

    },1000);
```

And in count.php

```
   $name=$_GET['name'];
   echo json_encode(array('status'=>TRUE,'name'=>$name));die;
```

Comment: this is what count.php looks like     $sql = "SELECT * FROM upload";
    $result = mysqli_query($db, $sql);
    $num_rows = mysqli_num_rows($result);

    echo $num_rows;

Comment: i am going to get the value of num rows but how do i store it in a php variable

Comment: @Jk you can json_encode the variable from the server.