# How to access data returned from an API using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, json, api

I'm doing an AJAX GET request to an API that returns all stores in my area that offer express delivery. I need to check over the data to see if any store in the area offer express delivery but can't access the data properly to perform any check's and don't understand why.

A stripped back version of the data returned from the API is here:

```json
{
"data": {
"service_eligibility": [
{
"accesspoint_list": [
{
"current_time": null,
"currency": null,
"accesspoint_id": "3242342-6dc1-43d8-b3d0-234234234234",
"service_info": {
"fulfillment_type": "DELIVERY",
"reservation_type": "SLOTS",
"dispense_type": "DELIVERY",
"priority": 0,
"carrier": "Owned",
"fulfillment_option": "DELIVERY",
"location_type": "Home",
"service_time": 0,
"is_recurring_slot": false,
"enable_express": false,
"is_unattended_slot": true,
"is_flex_slot": false
},
{
"current_time": null,
"currency": null,
"accesspoint_id": "234234242-3387-4e1d-9eaa-234234242",
"service_info": {
"fulfillment_type": "INSTORE_PICKUP",
"reservation_type": "SLOTS",
"dispense_type": "PICKUP_INSTORE",
"priority": 0,
"carrier": "NA",
"fulfillment_option": "PICKUP",
"location_type": "Store",
"service_time": 0,
"is_recurring_slot": false,
"enable_express": true,
"is_unattended_slot": false,
"is_flex_slot": false
},
"current_time": "2021-06-07T11:24:39Z",
"currency": "GBP"
},
"status_code": 200,
"status_message": "Requested input executed successfully."
}
```

The call I use to get my data:

```
                $.ajax({
                    type: 'GET',
                    dataType: "json",
                    url: query,
                    data: "",
                    success: function(data)
                    {
                        //Check for express delivery
                        if(data.status_code == 200) {
                            console.log(data);
                        }
                    },
                    error: function(data)
                    {
                        //Check for API error
                        if(data.status == 400){
                            console.log(data.responseJSON.errors[0].message);
                        }               
                    
                    }
                })
```

So far the data is being logged to the console. But when I try to access it or parts I want to use I get console errors.

I have tried copying the property path from the console and using it in the console.log:
`console.log(data.service_eligibility[0].accesspoint_list)`
but get the error message:
 `Cannot read property '0' of undefined`

I have tried just `data.service_eligibility` but this just give me the error of `undefined`

In fact even if I just try to access `data.currency` I get `undefined`

Why can I not access the data being returned from the API?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3302702/jquery-return-value-using-ajax-result-on-success

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-to-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call

Comment: Try : `data.data.service_eligibility[0].accesspoint_list`

Comment: That works, why do I have to put `data.data`?

Comment: because return response is inside `data` variable and your `accesspoint_list` is nested like this : `data > service_eligibility > accesspoint_list`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
                   type: 'GET',
                   dataType: "json",
                   url: query,
                   data: "",
                   success: function(data)
                   {
                       //Check for express delivery
                       if(data.status_code == 200) {
                        console.log(response.data.ervice_eligibility[0].accesspoint_list);
                       }
                   }
```

Looking at the above piece of code you have provided, it looks like, the `data` object that you are receiving in the success handler does not directly refer to the `data` object inside your received response. Given the names are same, it can be confusing.
I think if you try accessing the property inside the `data` object using `data.data.service_eligibility`, you will be able to access it. For some more clarity, see the code below:

```
                    type: 'GET',
                    dataType: "json",
                    url: query,
                    data: "",
                    success: function(response)
                    {
                        //Check for express delivery
                        if(response.status_code == 200) {
                            console.log(response.data.service_eligibility[0].accesspoint_list);

                      }
                    }
```

Just think about it, if your data is available inside the success handler, it means that the asynchronous action of fetching the data from the api has successfully completed. You can just debug the structure of your data object and find out what's missing or what's wrong in the way you are accessing a value. People can behave differently, code can never! :)

Comment: This is actually really useful, so I'd called my repsonse data?

Comment: Yes, try using the same code as above or just try to console.log(response) once it is available inside the success handler. Then you can see the clear structure of your response itself. You can also put a breakpoint in the first line of the success handler, and then in your browser console, you will get a hold of your response. Then you can play around with your response to find the right path to your data.