# flask Cannot access before initialization

Tags: javascript, python, jquery, ajax, flask

index.html

```
  <div class="div-inputs">
    <input type="text" id="input" placeholder="Enter expression" value="1+2"/>
    <input type="submit" id="btn" value="Execute"/>
  </div>
  <input type="text" id="output" readonly="readonly">
  
  <script src="{{url_for('static', filename='js/jquery-3.2.1.min.js')}}"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript">
    document.querySelector('#btn').addEventListener('click', (e) => {
      let equation = document.querySelector('#input').value;
      $.ajax({
        url: "/",
        type: "POST",
        data: equation,
        success: function(){
          console.log("successfull POST");
          let result = {{evaluate}}
          document.querySelector('#output').value = result;
        }
      });
    });
  </script>
```

main.py

```
from flask import Flask
from flask import url_for, jsonify, render_template, request, json
from math import *

app=Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/', methods=["GET","POST"])
def index() :
  
    evaluate = ""
    if request.method == 'POST':
        toEvalFromJS = request.get_json()
        evaluate = eval(str(toEvalFromJS))
        return render_template('index.html', evaluate=evaluate)
    
    return render_template('index.html')

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(port=10, debug=True)
```

error

```
(index):26 successfull POST
(index):28 Uncaught ReferenceError: Cannot access 'result' before initialization
    at Object.success ((index):28:53)
    at i (jquery-3.2.1.min.js:2:28017)
    at Object.fireWith [as resolveWith] (jquery-3.2.1.min.js:2:28783)
    at A (jquery-3.2.1.min.js:4:14035)
    at XMLHttpRequest.<anonymous> (jquery-3.2.1.min.js:4:16323)
```

I know what the error means but I could only get such far.

I have already read the following questions:

- [jquery - return value using ajax result on success](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3302702/jquery-return-value-using-ajax-result-on-success)
- [How to return the response from an asynchronous call](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-to-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call)

but they did not help me solve my problem.

What I want to do: User input an expression string, then click on the submit button and get the evaluated string back.

How could I get the evaluated string?

I am new to flask, I do it just for practice

Comment: always put code, data and full error message as text (not screenshot, not link) in question (not in comment).  It will be more readable and easier to use in answer, and more people will see it - so more people can help you.

Comment: @furas I have fixed it.

Comment: what do you have in `{{evaluate}}` ? Put some text instead of `{{evaluate}}` and check if it works.

Comment: you use `{{evalute}}` in wrong way. Flask puts value in `{{evalute}}` before it sends page to server. You can't use it to get value from ajax. You should use `data` in  `'success: function(data) {... use ... data... }` to get data from server. BTW: it looks strange - page `index.html` runs ajax to get the same `index.html`. Ajax usually is used to get some part of HTML or JSON data which is simpler to generate HTML on page.

Comment: evaluate come from `return render_template('index.html', evaluate=evaluate)` .  If I add some text instead of `{{evaluate}}` it is working, but then it cannot eval the string

Comment: maybe it will work better when you put `;` at the end `let result = {{evaluate}}` and you use `" "` to create string `let result = "{{evaluate}}";` because at this moment it may redner as `let result = document.querySelector('#output').value = result;` and this is wrong.

Comment: @furas this way `let result = "{{evaluate}}";` it is working, but I cannot get the output

Comment: you use `{{evaluate}` in wrong way. `{{evaluate}}` is part of Flask and it will not work in JavaScript as you expect. Flask first get template and replace `{{evaluate}}` with empty value and it sends to browser - and ajax get new page but it doesn't replace current page so it still have empty value in `{{evaluate}}`

Comment: you mix two separated words - you have to use `function(data) {...}` and you will get new FULL index.html in `data` (with new value in place `{{evaluate}}`)> But you should rather send AjAX to different url which will send only valeu without full HTML.

Comment: @furas so I have to post to other page, then get the data from that page?

Comment: yes, you have to post to other URL which sends back only expected value- and you should get it as `data` in `function(data) {... document.querySelector('#output').value =  data }`

Comment: you have another problem - `ajax` doesn't send it as JSON but as normal `form` and you have it in `request.form` and `get_json()` gives None. It may need to convert `equation`  to JSON in `$.ajax` before you send it. OR you have to get it as `reques.form` but it may convert `+` to space because usually browser use `+` instead of space when it sends some data - and later tools like Flask convert `+` back to space.

Comment: @furas I am using `data: JSON.stringify(equation)`  and `toEvalFromJS = request.get_json()`
`print(toEvalFromJS)` but it print None

Comment: in `$.ajax` it may need to add header something like `applications/json`. OR use `request.get_data()`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Main problem is that you use `{{evaluate}}` in wrong way. You expect that JavaScript will get data from server and it will replace `{{evaluate}}` with new value. But it is not true.

Flask replaces `{{evaluate}}` with empty string and it sends HTML with empty string - and browser when you load page `index.html` and
browser has HTML with empty string (it doesn't know that there was `{{evaluate}}`).

When `$.ajax` gets it agains then Flask replaces `{{evaluate}}` in template `index.html` and it sends new HTML with new value in place of `{{evaluate}}` but it can't replace empty string which you already have in original HTML in browser - it doesn't work this way.

`JavaScript` get new HTML in `data` in `sucess: function(data){...}` and you have to write code which uses this `data`. But it could be simpler if you would send ajax to separated URL which send back only result (without other HTML). And then it can display `data`

```
sucess: function(data){
   document.querySelector('#output').value = data;
}
```

---

Later there is another problem(s).

Ajax sends it with standard header for `POST form` and `Flask` see it and it convert data to `request.form` and it has empty `request.get_json` (because all is in `request.form`).

But some chars has special meaning  in `form` and `url` (ie. `+` is used instead of space) and it automatically unescapes data and it puts `space` instead of `+`.

To get `+` you have to get `raw data` using `request.get_data()`

Or you would have to send `ajax` with header `application/json` to use `get_json()`.

```
      $.ajax({
        ...
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",        
        ...        
      })
```

---

Minimal working code

I use `render_template_string` instead of `render_template` to put all in one file - and now everyone can simply copy and run it.

I also use `https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com` to load `jquery` so it doesn't need local file with `jquery`.

```py
from flask import Flask, url_for, jsonify, render_template_string, request, json
from math import *  # `import *` is not preferred

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/')
def index():
    return render_template_string("""
  <div class="div-inputs">
    <input type="text" id="input" placeholder="Enter expression" value="1+2"/>
    <input type="submit" id="btn" value="Execute"/>
  </div>
  <input type="text" id="output" readonly="readonly">
  
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.0/jquery.min.js" integrity="sha512-894YE6QWD5I59HgZOGReFYm4dnWc1Qt5NtvYSaNcOP+u1T9qYdvdihz0PPSiiqn/+/3e7Jo4EaG7TubfWGUrMQ==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"></script>

  <script type="text/javascript">
    document.querySelector('#btn').addEventListener('click', (e) => {
      let equation = document.querySelector('#input').value;
      $.ajax({
        url: "/data",
        type: "POST",

        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",        

        data: JSON.stringify(equation),
        success: function(data){
          console.log("successfull POST");
          console.log(data);
          document.querySelector('#output').value = data;
        }
      });
    });
  </script>
""")

@app.route('/data', methods=['POST'])
def data():
    print('json:', request.get_json())  # `None` if there is no `contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8"` in `$.ajax`

    print('data:', request.get_data())
    print('form:', request.form)

    equation = json.loads(request.get_data().decode())
    print('equation:', equation)
    
    if equation:
        result = eval(equation)
    else:
        result = "wrong data"
        
    return jsonify(result)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    #app.debug = True
    app.run(port=5010)
```

Comment: I did not expect such a detailed answer, so huge thanks to you.

Comment: it needed many explanations. I added also `contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",` in description.