# javascript : why ajax in function return undefined?

Tags: javascript, ajax, function

I have a function with ajax in it :

```
    function get_cart_count(){
      $.ajax({
        url: "/cart/count",
        method: "get",
        async: false,
        success: function (count) {
            if (count > 0) {
                // console.log('count is :' + count);
                return count;
            }
        },
      });
    }
```

as you see the async is false.

the `count is`  log is 1,
but when I `console.log(get_cart_count())` , it give me undefined !
why this happening ?

thanks

Comment: Does this answer your question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5316697/jquery-return-data-after-ajax-call-success

Comment: Also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3302702/jquery-return-value-using-ajax-result-on-success